# Directshow transform filter converts Bayer 8bit to YUY2

Tags: directshow

I am developing custom transform filter that is converting RAW Bayer frames from camera to RGB24 frames. I have properly modified MediaType attributes of output pin(RGB24)  in GetMediaType() function. Still my modifications for Output pin for e.g. biBitCount, biCompression, biSizeImage are not reflecting in property window of PIN. And when I render output PIN and run the graph it shows parameter is incorrect error.
What is wrong with my flow or can anyone explain me what are the steps I needs to implement for my filter to work.

This is my GetMediaType() function in which I am modifying output pin's attributes.

```
HRESULT CYuvGray::GetMediaType(int iPosition, CMediaType *pMediaType)
{




    ASSERT(m_pInput->IsConnected());

    if (iPosition < 0)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    else if (iPosition == 0)
    {  


        HRESULT hr =  m_pInput->ConnectionMediaType(pMediaType);

        const GUID* rgb = &MEDIASUBTYPE_YUY2;


        //pMediaType->SetTemporalCompression(FALSE);
        //pMediaType->SetType();

         /*VIDEOINFOHEADER *pVih =
            reinterpret_cast<VIDEOINFOHEADER*>(pMediaType->pbFormat);*/

        VIDEOINFOHEADER *pVih = (VIDEOINFOHEADER *)pMediaType->AllocFormatBuffer(sizeof(VIDEOINFOHEADER));

        pVih->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 16;
        pVih->bmiHeader.biCompression = mmioFOURCC('Y', 'U', 'Y', '2');//BI_RGB;//mmioFOURCC('Y', 'U', 'Y', '2');
        //pVih->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = pVih->bmiHeader.biHeight * pVih->bmiHeader.biWidth * 2;


        pVih->bmiHeader.biSize       = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        pVih->bmiHeader.biPlanes     = 1;
        pVih->bmiHeader.biSizeImage  = GetBitmapSize(&pVih->bmiHeader);
        pVih->bmiHeader.biClrImportant   = 0;

        SetRectEmpty(&(pVih->rcSource)); // we want the whole image area rendered.
        SetRectEmpty(&(pVih->rcTarget)); // no particular destination rectangle

        pMediaType->SetType(&MEDIATYPE_Video);
        pMediaType->SetFormatType(&FORMAT_VideoInfo);
        pMediaType->SetTemporalCompression(FALSE);
        pMediaType->SetSampleSize(pVih->bmiHeader.biSizeImage);   


        pMediaType->SetSubtype(rgb);             //Set output type to RGB24
        //pMediaType->SetSampleSize(pMediaType->GetSampleSize() * 2);

        //pMediaType->SetFormat(PBYTE(pVih), sizeof(VIDEOINFOHEADER));   
        //pVih->dwBitRate = pVih->dwBitRate * 3 ;
        //m_pOutput->SetMediaType(pMediaType);
        return S_OK;
    }
    return VFW_S_NO_MORE_ITEMS;
}
```

Comment: For the record, this is a cross-post and continues what began here: [How to implement transform filter for custom format](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/c4fee036-545b-4bbc-91a1-3e3c7e79438f/how-to-implement-transform-filter-for-custom-format?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment)

Comment: `const GUID* rgb = &MEDIASUBTYPE_YUY2` and `//Set output type to RGB24` are a bit confusing....

Comment: Its just name. Actually I am setting YUY2 as SUBMEDIA TYPE here.